# How to get PID of process when using XVFB via Pyvirtualdisplay?

Tags: python, pid, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

Trying to find the PID of a Display object when creating it using Pyvirtualdisplay.  The display an Xvfb virtual framebuffer.

We have tried looking at the `.pid` property, but it is not present.  Also, the `.process` property is non existant.  Both raise an `AttributeError` error when accessed.

Thanks very much! Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this situation is to actually use the `.pid` property on the display object, BUT, it is only present *after* the display has had the `start` method called on it.  That means, if you need to get the PID for the process, the display has to be started first.